# Avatar changed automatically

Tags: support

I have noticed that my avatar beside my user name has been modified, not by me. Has anyone noticed this (their own avatar, not mine!)? I had a generic blue and white patterned tile, now it is grey and white and a slightly different pattern.

I'm not really bothered by the avatar but has my profile been changed without me knowing it/approving it?

Comment: this has been going on for some time now, and has been the topic of a vigorous discussion on the chat.  this post, on the "main" meta site, seems to be the canonical source of information: [Why is my profile image different?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283643/169475).  it *is* possible to change it yourself, which will make it permanent.

Comment: Just as a reference, this has also been noticed on [physics.SE](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9093/my-profile-picture-pattern-just-changed-automatically-how-can-i-restore-the-old).

Comment: @heather It's cross-network: really one for the central meta

Comment: If this bothers you: You can upload your own avatar image. As far as I know this does not change

Comment: As long as it's not due to someone trying to mess with my head, I'm not too bothered! And just because I am paranoid doesn't mean they're not out to get me ;)